# CSS - Links moving on hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

I'm having a slight issue with some CSS I'm working on.

Links in the footer moves a little when on hover, but only after I refresh the page, on first load all looks good but after I refresh the page the links are sitting tight to each other and when hovered they go back to their proper position, tried few tricks found on Stack, but they didn't help.

Here is the code:

```
.f-links {
    clear:both;
float:right;
    position:relative;
    left:-50%;
    text-align:left;
}

.f-links ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    left:45%;
}

.f-links li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.f-links a {
font-size:12px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    float:left;
    padding:2px 10%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.f-links a:hover,
.f-links a:visited {
    color: black;
}

.f-links a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="f-links">

            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>

            </div><!-- /f-links -->
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why do you float the `a` s?

Comment: That's taken from one solution I found on here, I wanted to position the links right in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you only want to center the links you better use following css (`inline-block` is [well supported](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) so no worries)

```
.f-links {
    text-align: center;
}

.f-links ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.f-links li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the float left  and the percentage from padding in the .f-link a styles:

```
.f-links a {
font-size:12px;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: underline;
color: black;
padding:2px 10px;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I removed them, but that didn't fix the problem.